# Best way to query different database engines in a uniform way?

Tags: c#, sql, database, portability

I work on a C# client application ([SlimTune Profiler](http://slimtune.com)) that uses relational (and potentially embedded) database engines as its backing store. The current version already has to deal with SQLite and SQL Server Compact, and I'd like to experiment with support for other systems like MySQL, Firebird, and so on. Worse still, I'd like it to support plugins for *any* other backing data store -- and not necessarily ones that are SQL based, ideally. Topping off the cake, the frontend itself supports plugins, so I have an unknown many-to-many mapping between querying code and engines handling the queries.

Right now, queries are basically handled via raw SQL code. I've already run into trouble making complex SELECTs work in a portable way. The problem can only get worse over time, and that doesn't even consider the idea of supporting non-SQL data. So then, what is the best way to query wildly disparate engines in a sane way?

I've considered something based on LINQ, possibly the [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) project. Another option is object persistence frameworks, [Subsonic](http://forums.subsonicproject.com/) for example. But I'm not too sure what's out there, what the limitations are, or if I'm just hoping for too much.

(An aside, for the inevitable question of why I don't settle on one engine. I like giving the user a choice of the engine that works best for them. SQL Compact allows replication to a full SQL Server instance. SQLite is portable and supports in-memory databases. I can imagine a situation where a company wants to drop in a MySQL plugin so that they can easily store and collate an application's performance data over the course of time. Last and most importantly, I find the idea that I should have to be dependent on the implementation details of my underlying database engine to be absurd.)

Comment: It's *absurd* you're tying yourself to c#/.net if that's how you think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object-relational mapper.  This will provide a high level of abstraction away from the different database engines, and won't impose (many) limitations on the kind of queries you can run.  Many ORMs also include LINQ support.  There are numerous questions on SO providing recommendations and comparisons (e.g. [What is your favorite ORM for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214448/) appears to be the most recent and has links to several others).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use an interface for all of your database access. Then for each database type you want to support to do the implementation of the interface for that database. That is what I've had to do for projects in the past.

The problem with many database systems and storage tools is that they aim to solve different problems. You might not even want to store your data in a SQL database but instead store it as files in the App_Data folder of a web application. With an interface method you could do that quite easily.

There generally isn't a solution that fits all database and storage solutions well or even a few of them well. If you find one that claims it does I still wouldn't trust it. When you have a problem with one of the databases it's going to be much easier for you to dig through your objects than it will be to go dig through theirs.

Comment: But note that to support non relational backends you'd have to cook up SQL emulating code, which is far from trivial, and very far from the actual reason for the program to exist. Not that it isn't fun...

Comment: Have considered this, but I'm not especially thrilled that it restricts the possible queries to the rather small set that the interface accounts for. At least with raw SQL, I don't have to be prescient about the types of queries people will want to make on the data.

Comment: @Vinko: Why would you have to emulate SQL when implementing an interface?

Comment: @Filburt: True, I think I was thinking at a lower level. You can indeed implement a higher level 'business' interface.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the repository pattern. You can create a class that encapsulates all the actions that you need the database for, and then create a different implementation for each database type you want to support. In many cases, for relationional data stores, you can use the ADO.NET abstractions (IDbConnection, IDataReader, IDataAdapter, etc) and create a single generic repository, and only write specific implementations for the database types that do not provide an ADO.NET driver.

```
public interface IExecutionResultsRepository
{
  void SaveExecutionResults(string name, ExecutionResults results);
  ExecutionResults GetExecutionResults(int id);
}
```

I don't actually know what you are storing, so you'd have to adapt this for your actual needs. I'm also guessing this would require some heavy refactoring as you might have sql statements littered throughout your code. And pulling these out and encapsulating them might not be feasible. But IMO, that's the best way to achieve what you want to do.